# Need solution to: "Sorry an error occurred object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that uses information from a set of text boxes in a userform to find and edit values in two workbooks. The code that I am using to edit the values in the second workbook gives me the following error, "Sorry an Error Occurred Object doesn't support this property or method". Can anyone help me with this? Aside from what is causing the error I think my code is correct but if anyone sees any errors in my code by all means please feel free to correct me or offer suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim password As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
password = TextBox1.Text
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Accounts")
lastrow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lastrow
If WS.Cells(r, 2) = Label5.Caption Then
WS.Cells(r, 2).Value = TextBox1.Text
WS.Cells(r, 3).Value = TextBox2.Text
WS.Cells(r, 4).Value = TextBox3.Text
MsgBox "Update Successful", vbInformation
TextBox1.Text = ""
Call Edit_Login
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
End If
Next
MsgBox "Data not Found!!", vbCritical
TextBox1.Text = ""
Unload Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: MsgBox "Sorry an Error occured. " & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Information", vbCritical
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Edit_Login()
Dim Wkbk As Workbook
Dim txt As String
Dim txt2 As String
Dim txt3 As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim Account As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Account = TextBox1.Text
Set Wkbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kameron\Desktop\Quality Improvement 
Software\Log In.xlsm")
lastrow = Wkbk.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lastrow
If Wkbk.Sheets("Tables").Cells(r, 1) = Label5.Caption Then
Wkbk.Sheets("Tables").Cells(r, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text
Wkbk.Sheets("Tables").Cells(r, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
Wkbk.Sheets("Tables").Cells(r, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
MsgBox "Update Successful", vbInformation
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
Unload EditAccount
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
End If
Next
MsgBox "Data not Found!!", vbCritical
TextBox1.Text = ""
Unload Me
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: MsgBox "Sorry an Error occured. " & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Information", vbCritical
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
lastrow = Wkbk.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Workbook objects don't have a `Cells` property.

In context, you seem to want

```
lastrow = Wkbk.Sheets("Tables").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

In order to track down this error, you could have done one of two things:

1) Stepped through the code using F8 and see what line it fails on.

2) Temporarily commented out the line `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` and run the code.

Either approach would have quickly led to that line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the tip! I tried stepping through the code like you suggested. I will make sure I try that next time to see what I come up with. Your solution worked amazingly well!

Comment: @Kam `Wkbk` is declared `As Workbook`. When you later use it and type the dot after `Wkbk`, the VBE brings up an in-editor dropdown that lists all available members.